# How come the wiggles 2 addon work well in eevee but not cycles?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

As I assign certain bones to wiggle, in eevee, the animation is pretty smooth and flawless.

In cycles however, the wiggle bones twitch badly...

I find it really odd as to what a render engine that is meant to affect lighting has anything to do with bone animation and physics simulation? How are they connected and is there a solution to this?